# Let $α$ be an element of $\mathbb F_q$ with largest order $t$ . Show that set of elements with order dividing $t$ should have cardinality $t$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Let $α$ be an element of $\mathbb F_q$ with largest order $t$ . Show that set of elements with order dividing $t$ should have cardinality $t$, so there
must be some non-zero element $γ ∈ \mathbb F_q$ with $a = ord(γ)$ not dividing $t$.

I have no idea how to start. Please help

Comment: Multiplicative order, I presume? I mean, in fact $\;\alpha\in\Bbb F_q^*\;$ ...? And what is $\;\gamma\;$ ? And is $\;q\;$ a prime or a power of a prime?

Comment: This does not seem right because $\mathbb F_q^\times$ is cyclic.